# how to set Universal link in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm prepared for everything that I need to use universal link.
(made a AASA and checked it has no any problem with aasa-validator. and also set in XCODE and other things like that)

and now, I have to set up a hyperlink in my webpage to go the app.
but I don't know how it works and how to set it up.

when a button clicked, web will open a app.
I need some URL that for moving to app.

what kind of URL that I have to set it up?
I tried some URL as below.

```
$('#myButton').on('click', ()=>{ location.href = "https://example.com/somepage"})
```

and

```
$('#myButton').on('click', ()=>{ location.href = "https://example.com/apple-app-site-association" })
```

As you might expect, if you try the above you will be able to simply move to the page or download the AASA file.

because I don't understand exactly this mechanism, I just tried in many ways.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't refer to the ASAA file in your web site.  It simply needs to be hosted at the root or in the .well-known directory off the root.

In your app you add the domain of your web site to the associated-domains entitlement.

This entitlement causes iOS to fetch the ASAA file from your web site when your app is installed (and refresh it periodically).

In your ASAA file you list the paths that you want to launch your app.  When the user navigates to a matching path in Safari on their iOS device, iOS launches your app and passes the URL.

For example:

You might list `/news/*` in your ASAA file.

When someone browses to `https://example.com/news/Article1234` iOS will launch your app and pass in the URL.

You need to receive that URL in your iOS app, parse it and take the appropriate action (e.g. move the the "News" view controller and display article 1234).

The process is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

Comment: thank you for your replying! if each page(app and web) has same URL then the universal rink might not run in web right?

Comment: That's the idea. If a URL matches the path in your ASAA file then your app is launched to handle it. If your app is not installed then the web page is shown. You can see this with YouTube. If your click on a YouTube link, the app opens if it is installed. If not, the web version is shown.  What are you trying to do?  Perhaps you just want an app URL scheme, not a universal link

Comment: I was trying to use universal link to make the app move more smoothly. I have another question, does Universal Link automatically move to the web if the app is not installed even if I don't set it up?

Comment: Yes, that is what Universal links do; If the app is installed and has the correct associated domains entitlement then the app is opened.  If the app isn't installed then you stay in Safari,